# Lots of _dta_ indexes and stats on Production database, but is_hypothetical = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

There are 1,500 indexes and 2,300 stats beginning with *dta* on one of our databases.

I read that SQL Database Tuner sometimes leaves *dta* indexes behind, which are 
 hypothetical indexes and stats. But, when I check the properties of these, is_hypothetical is equal to 0.

Why is this?

I'd ideally like to delete all of these to try improve performance, but the fact they are not hypothetical I am unsure whether I should do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that someone blindly accepted the recommendations of the database tuning advisor and told it to build all the recommended indexes and stats.

Chances are you will discover lots of them can be combined or just outright deleted.

You'll find some useful links here for investigating likely candidates for removal. [How to determine if an Index is required or necessary](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56/3690)

Comment: I thought this alright, thanks. This is the only database (compared to 20 other client databases) that has these dta indexes and stats. With this in mind, it's more than likely okay to just delete all of these dta indexes+stats, would you agree? Deleting the indexes is fine, but I have never deleted stats so just wondering if there could be some knock on impact.

Comment: @PaulS - It might cause an execution plan regression - the DTA presumably recommended them because it thought they would be useful. But the vast majority of databases get on fine with just auto stats and no user created ones at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info. By the looks of things they are the only client that have applied these stats and indexes and coincidentally they are the main site to report slowness. I think I will plan to delete these! Cheers!